# Expected value of joint discrete continuous distribution

Tags: conditional-expectation

This is a problem from *All of Statistics* by Wasserman that I have been struggling with for a while.

**Problem**

Let $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Let $0<a<b<1$. Let
\begin{equation}
Y = 
\begin{cases}
1 & 0<x<b\\
0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Z = 
\begin{cases}
1 & a<x<1\\
0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

a) Are $Y$, $Z$ independent? Why/Why not?

b) Find $E(Y|Z)$. Hint: What values $z$ can $Z$ take?

Comment: related problem that I was looking at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473537/joint-distribution-of-discrete-and-continuous

Comment: There are only $2\times 2 = 4$ possible values for $(Y,Z).$  Make a table of their probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the comments above, I believe I figured it out:

Using the fact that $X\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$,

$$P(Y=1,Z=1)=P(x\in(0,b)~\land x\in(a,1)) = b-a$$

Similarly,

$$P(Y=1)P(Z=1) = b(1-a) $$

This shows that $Y,Z$ are dependent.

For part (b), following the hint, we have

\begin{align}
E(Y|Z=z) &= \sum_{y} y P(Y=y | Z = z) \\
&= \sum_{y} y P(Y=y,Z=z)/P(Z=z)\\
&= 0 + (1)P(Y=1,Z=z)/P(Z=z)\\
&= P(Y=1,Z=z)/P(Z=z)\\
\end{align}

Compute the probabilities $P(Y=1,Z=z)$ and $P(Z=z)$ for $Z=0,1$ to find
\begin{align}
E(Y|Z=z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{b-a}{1-a} & z=1\\
1 & z=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}